# iOS Parse RSS Feed, Get Image Link Strings

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, rss, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to parse a RSS feed in a test project. The feed doesn't have any image links but under the description tag i have found the img tags which are as follow:

```
<img src="//t0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRAWptM4WssgVQnzjto-Xys9x1sDZO8a34056rEG3gI1AhG30zOgEz-N-_hGpX-87WRIEqZidg" alt="" border="1" width="80" height="80" /><br /><font size="-2">San Francisco Chronicle</font></a></font></td><td valign="top" class="j"><font style="font-size:85%;font-family:arial,sans-serif"><br /><div style="padding-top:0.8em;"><img alt="" height="1" width="1" />
```

What i need to do is to retrieve the image links. I have found a method on SO which is as follow:

```
-(NSString *)getFirstImageUrl: (NSString *) html {

    NSScanner *theScanner;
    NSString *imageURL = nil;

    theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString: html];

    // find start of tag
    [theScanner scanUpToString: @"<img" intoString: NULL];
    if ([theScanner isAtEnd] == NO) {

        [theScanner scanUpToString: @"src=\"" intoString: NULL];
        NSInteger newLoc2 = [theScanner scanLocation] + 5;
        [theScanner setScanLocation: newLoc2];

        // find end of tag
        [theScanner scanUpToString: @"\"" intoString: &imageURL];
    }

    return imageURL;
}
```

So i have tried using the above method:

```
NSString *imageURLString;
    if (newImageString) {
        imageURLString = [self getFirstImageUrl:newImageString];
        NSLog(@"IMAGE URL STRING %@", imageURLString);
    }
```

But the project crashes with the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSConcreteScanner setScanLocation:]: Index 2332 out of bounds; string length 2327'
```

Can any one help me to point out what is wrong with it and how can i get the image url strings? Thanks!

Comment: Why you add 5 here NSInteger newLoc2 = [theScanner scanLocation] + 5;

Comment: @EugeneProkoshev i just copied this method from a question. Apparently its because when it finds "src=\"" the location is set before the s of the src. Plus 5 makes sure it starts from after the "src=\"" from where the url starts and what i want.

Comment: But this give you a NSExeption because the theScanner range is exactly 5  less then newLoc2;

Comment: @EugeneProkoshev i have used this method with other feeds where it works fine with this specific feed i am unable to troubleshoot the problem. Removing +5 doesn't raise the exception but it still returns null values.

Comment: It seems that after you check that [theScaner isAtEnd] you will receive false, because you still have something to scan and this is last feed. But after you try to change scanner location and add 5 to the newLoc2 the location is out of the scanner range.

Comment: @EugeneProkoshev there is absolutely nothing wrong with +5. Sometimes it returns correctly sometimes it crashes that is why i am unable to troubleshoot it. You can use this method is a separate program and it will work without any issue. But i am unable to understand why it is giving me index out of bounds exception

Comment: Hm.. then it very strange coz index is exactly out of bounds by 5. `Index 2332 out of bounds; string length 2327'` so string that you try to scan is less then index of your newLoc2.

Comment: @EugeneProkoshev Well let me assure you that +5 has nothing to do with this issue. I have tried it with other feeds and it works just fine. I am not sure but i think that the problem is that other feeds has a normal url starting from http: while this feed has urls starting from //t0.gstatic.com/ as you can see in the question. I have to manually add http: that is equal to 5 in characters before every url. But i dont know how to solve it yet